# Odoo: URL not found if not auth

Tags: odoo-9

I have controller with route:

```
@http.route(['/report/yandex_phone_report'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def yandex_phone_report(self, **kw):
    page_data = []


    return  http.request.render(self._report_index_page_template, {
        'page_items': page_data
```

If I logged in  URL /report/yandex_phone_report displayed fine.
If I not loged in URL /report/yandex_phone_report is returning 404:

```
2017-08-02 16:46:09,400 5942 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2017 16:46:09] "GET /report/yandex_phone_report HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Browser is displaying this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

How can I fix it? Why route is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because it doesn't know on which database to look for that URL.

If you look on the log you provided, you will see that after INFO, you have ?

```
2017-08-02 16:46:09,400 5942 INFO ? <- THIS ONE
```

Instead of ?, you see a database name, if it knows which database it should use.

To test it, you can first call: http://localhost:PORT/web?db=YOUR_DB_NAME

This will setup the session on the browser for the given database.

Then, calling http://localhost:PORT/report/yandex_phone_report will work.

On a production environment, you will need to configure it to get the database name from somewhere... From the URL, for instance (http://dbname.example.com:PORT).

Answer (score 0):

With multi-db environment you can have `auth='none'` but also your module needs to be added to odoo.conf `server_wide_modules`
This way the route will be added. At least in Odoo 13.
https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/server_wide_modules.html

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation for that `server_wide_modules` configuration?