# When i try to add record to my model using odoo controller I got this error "The requested URL was not found on the server"

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I wrote this inside my module controller

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
class Mylib(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/mylib/project', auth='public',method=['POST'], csrf=False)
    def fun_post(self):
              vals = {'name': 'The secret', 'author': 'shakesphere', 'year': 1661, 
             'book_copy': 12}

              return request.env['books.model'].create(vals)
```

after running this there is no record added, that may be the problem with the URL. I don't know how to put this route...I checked via postman then I got this error,

```
" The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the 
 URL manually please check your spelling and try again"
```

Comment: Try to add `type="http", auth="public", ...` to your decorator and tell us if it works then?

Comment: No again i got same error                                                                                       
        " The requested URL was not found "

Comment: What URL did you try?

Comment: I used this as URL                                                                            "localhost:8022/mylib/project"

Comment: Okay, the port is correct (it's not default)? Do you use a webproxy?

Comment: sorry i'm not using a proxy

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using POSTMAN. I saw this answer [Odoo: URL not found if not auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45468658/8325806)  and then added

> --db-filter=[YOUR DB]

in the `odoo-bin` execution command. don't add in `odoo.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Hope the indentation of your function is correct and is defined inside the class Mylib.

If you are calling this URL from an external source or without logging into the system you have to mention the DB details if you have multiple DBS.

Comment: how can i mention the particular db details?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code: I added *type='json'* in the argument and return a string instead of *books.model* recordset.

```
@http.route('/mylib/project', type='json', auth='public', method=['POST'], csrf=False)
def fun_post(self):
    vals = {'name': 'The secret', 'author': 'shakesphere', 'year': 1661,
            'book_copy': 12}
    request.env['books.model'].create(vals)
    return "OK"
```

If still not working, add *dbfilter=YOUR-DB-NAME* in the .conf file or if you run the server from the command line then add *-d YOUR-DB-NAME*